# If we increase the mass of a black hole by a factor of $k$, by what factor will the surface area of the event horizon change?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon, estimation

1. If we increase the mass of a black hole by a factor of $k$, by what factor will the surface area of the event horizon change?
2. Given any number of identical black holes each with mass = $\mathrm{m_0}$ and surface area = $\mathrm{A_0}$ what can we say about the surface area of a black hole resulting from their collision?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I have a decent background in pure mathematics but very little experience with physical theories like general relativity.

Comment: have you considered the membrane approach and 3+1 decomposition?[link](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/5045/1/PRIprd86.pdf)

Answer (score 9):

The [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) is:

$$ r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2} $$

so the area will be proportional to mass squared.

However if you combine two black holes the mass of the resulting bigger black hole is generally less than the sum of the individual masses. This is because energy is radiated as gravitational waves during the merger.

Answer (score 4):

Lets consider GR units with $G=c=1$. In (3+1) dimensions, the mass would have units of length, so a factor of $k$ would introduce a factor of $k^2$ on the EH's area. However, if you are working in a different number of dimensions, take care on the units of the mass ($[m]=L^{d-3}$), where $d$ is the total number of dimensions.